# how to resume copying the files where it stopped

Tags: python, linux, rsync, cp

I was copying the file from my system to the hard disk. Because of the power problem the progress of the copy got halted.

So I want to copy the files from the files where it left

I used the command

```
cp -rv /home/naity/data /media/pendrive
```

I want to use `rsync` to resumpton of the copy from where it left.

So can anybody suggest some better solution for the same.Thanks.

Comment: I would just start it all over again. If you system suddenly lost power without shutting down or flushing its buffers, you may have corrupted files. Delete them all and start over.

Comment: I donot think whole files are corrupted the last file may be.....moreover 120gb files already copied another 50gb left

Comment: Well, since you originally tagged Python (I've since added it back), you could use the various functions in the `os` and `shutil` modules to check if the file exists in the new location and if the file size is the same as the original, then skip it if so.

Comment: please suggest a solution, I donot know how to do it @MattDMo

Comment: better copy again - and you could calculate `hash` for every file to check if they are correct. As I know `rsync` also use `hash` to check which files it has to send again.

Answer (score 0):

rsync is the better tool because of the built-in logic to compare SOURCE and REPLICA directories and contents, and only copy what needs to be copied to make a full duplicate.

The command you would normally use would be

```
SOURCE="/home/naity/data"
REPLICA="/media/pendrive/"

rsync --recursive --delete-delay --verbose "${SOURCE}" "${REPLICA}"
```

If you intend the process to create a folder/directory named "data" under the REPLICA target, then the above is the way to specify the SOURCE.

If you expect the "data" folder itself (not referring to content) to pre-exist already on the REPLICA, then you would need to add "data/" at the end of the definition for REPLICA, as well as add a "/" at the end of the definition for SOURCE.

Adding **--delete-delay** will ensure rsync removes any files for which there is no duplicate in SOURCE (that includes partly copied files, from cp or rsync, that are leftovers from a powerfail condition).

**Since you are not familiar with rsync**, it is highly recommended that you **create a dummy test repository (about 5 files)** and verify the command structure for that small amount of data to ensure that all is working to your satisfaction before putting in the real archive directory with that 120 GB of data.